# How to list of ports and Mac addresses to connected switch (Cisco) C#

Tags: c#, .net, net-snmp

Hello everyone I want to ask about how can list ports and mac addresses of devices connected to switch using C#.
I have found code which works for Dell switch. I need it for Cisco switch

```
using SnmpSharpNet;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
 
namespace PortMapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
 
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> portList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        List<Portmap> portMaps = new List<Portmap>();
 
        public class Portmap
        {
            public string Hostname { get; set; }
            public string Port { get; set; }
            public string IP { get; set; }
            public string MAC { get; set; }
        }
 
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.2");
            IPAddress ip2 = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.3");
            SnmpWalk(ip, "community", "1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1", "1");
            SnmpWalk(ip2, "community","1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2.1", "2");
            DhcpQuery("netsh", "dhcp server \\\\servername scope 192.168.0.0 show clients", "192");
            List<Portmap> gridResults = new List<Portmap>();
            //Example of filtering uplink ports from other switches
            foreach(Portmap portMap in portMaps)
            {
                if (portMap.Port != "1/2/48" && portMap.Port != "2/1/48")
                {
                    gridResults.Add(portMap);
                }
            }
            PortMapGrid.ItemsSource = gridResults;
        }
         
        //Use NETSH to retrieve a list of DHCP MAC and IP addresses
        private void DhcpQuery(string cmd, string args, string subnet)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.FileName = cmd;
            procStartInfo.Arguments = args;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            string output;
            using (Process proc = Process.Start(procStartInfo))
            {
                output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
 
            //Find valid leases in command output
            string[] lines = output.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            List<string> leases = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith(subnet))
                {
                   leases.Add(line);
                }
            }
 
            //Create threads
            Thread[] threadArray = new Thread[leases.Count];
            int threadcount = 0;
 
            //Loop each Dhcp Lease
            foreach (string line in leases)
            {
                string[] pieces = line.Split('-');
                string ipAddress = pieces[0].Trim();
                string mac = "";
                string hostname = "";
                foreach (string piece in pieces)
                {
                    if (piece.Trim().Length == 2)
                    {
                        mac += piece;
                    }
                }
 
                ThreadStart start = delegate
                {
                    hostname = GetHost(ipAddress);
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> port in portList)
                    {
                        if (port.Key.ToUpper().Trim() == mac.ToUpper().Trim())
                        {
                            Portmap portMap = new Portmap();
                            portMap.IP = ipAddress;
                            portMap.MAC = mac.ToUpper();
                            portMap.Port = port.Value;
                            portMap.Hostname = hostname;
                            portMaps.Add(portMap);
                        }
                    }
                };
                threadArray[threadcount] = new Thread(start);
                threadArray[threadcount].Start();
                threadcount = threadcount + 1;
            }
 
            //Join all threads in the array to wait for results
            for (int i = 0; i < threadcount; i++)
            {
                threadArray[i].Join();
            }
        }
 
        //SNMPWALK the ports on a switch or stack of switches. Ports will be labeled SwitchNum/Stack Number/Port Numbers.
        private void SnmpWalk(IPAddress ip, string snmpCommunity, string oid, string switchNum)
        {
            UdpTarget target = new UdpTarget(ip);
 
            // SNMP community name
            OctetString community = new OctetString(snmpCommunity);
            // Define agent parameters class
            AgentParameters param = new AgentParameters(community);
            // Set SNMP version to 1
            param.Version = SnmpVersion.Ver1;
 
 
            // Define Oid that is the root of the MIB tree you wish to retrieve
            Oid rootOid = new Oid(oid);
 
            // This Oid represents last Oid returned by the SNMP agent
            Oid lastOid = (Oid)rootOid.Clone();
 
            // Pdu class used for all requests
            Pdu pdu = new Pdu(PduType.GetNext);
 
            // Loop through results
            while (lastOid != null)
            {
                // When Pdu class is first constructed, RequestId is set to a random value
                // that needs to be incremented on subsequent requests made using the
                // same instance of the Pdu class.
                if (pdu.RequestId != 0)
                {
                    pdu.RequestId += 1;
                }
                // Clear Oids from the Pdu class.
                pdu.VbList.Clear();
                // Initialize request PDU with the last retrieved Oid
                pdu.VbList.Add(lastOid);
                // Make SNMP request
                SnmpV1Packet result = (SnmpV1Packet)target.Request(pdu, param);
                // You should catch exceptions in the Request if using in real application.
 
                // If result is null then agent didn't reply or we couldn't parse the reply.
                if (result != null)
                {
                    // ErrorStatus other then 0 is an error returned by 
                    // the Agent - see SnmpConstants for error definitions
                    if (result.Pdu.ErrorStatus != 0)
                    {
                        // agent reported an error with the request
                        Console.WriteLine("Error in SNMP reply. Error {0} index {1}",
                            result.Pdu.ErrorStatus,
                            result.Pdu.ErrorIndex);
                        lastOid = null;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Walk through returned variable bindings
                        foreach (Vb v in result.Pdu.VbList)
                        {
                            // Check that retrieved Oid is "child" of the root OID
                            if (rootOid.IsRootOf(v.Oid))
                            {
                                //Convert OID to MAC
                                string[] macs = v.Oid.ToString().Split('.');
                                string mac = "";
                                int counter = 0;
                                foreach (string chunk in macs)
                                {
                                    if (counter >= macs.Length - 6)
                                    {
                                        mac += string.Format("{0:X2}", int.Parse(chunk));
                                    }
                                    counter += 1;
                                }
 
                                //Assumes a 48 port switch (52 actual). You need to know these values to correctly iterate through a stack of switches.
                                int dellSwitch = 1 + int.Parse(v.Value.ToString()) / 52;
                                int port = int.Parse(v.Value.ToString()) - (52 * (dellSwitch - 1));
                                KeyValuePair<string, string> Port = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(mac, switchNum + "/" + dellSwitch.ToString() + "/" + port.ToString());
                                portList.Add(Port);
 
                                //Exit Loop
                                lastOid = v.Oid;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //End of the requested MIB tree. Set lastOid to null and exit loop
                                lastOid = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No response received from SNMP agent.");
                }
            }
            target.Close();
        }
 
        private string GetHost(string ipAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);
                return entry.HostName;
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can Anyone is going to help me out for finding the code or give me a way that how can I convert this code to work for Cisco. what Oid it can be?

Comment: That code should work for a cisco switch as well. http://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2

Comment: Is it just me or should the community string you pass in be `"public"` rather than `"community"`? I mean, I guess you could configure SNMP on the switches differently.

Comment: it depends upon the configuration of SNMP on your network. if you configured community then it should.